# How can a web page run a program on client's computer?

Tags: visual-studio, activex

I developed a web software with Visual Studio. Within this web software when I click on a button, the user's computer should run an application given as an .exe file. This application is a console application and it needs to receive commandline parameters.

I've tried to run it with Javascript, but it was removed due to security issues.

```
     Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\ProgramAdres\Program.exe")
     startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
     startInfo.Arguments = "arguments"
     Process.Start(startInfo)
```

This code successfuly runs the application, but on the server side. I need your help because I do not know ActiveXand don't know how to start.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know English very well. May be misspelled. I wanted to do something: the user's web browser to run applications from program path. These applications path : "c:\program files\ApplicationName.exe"

Comment: Ok, there's no problem - that's why I asked. I'll rearrange your question a little. However, I don't know how to help you solve it.

Comment: No matter. Thank you.

Comment: The browser should not allow you to start any application. What if someone wanted to start `Format.exe` with argument `C:`?

Comment: :) 
After allowing the user format.exe usable. However, already are normally difficult to format, while internet browser is not at all.
Is already being used in some applications. My goal is not hopping distance format. We can see that in some applications.